# Arch Linux doesn't seem to use vconsole.conf

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I have insalled Arch Linux. During the installation, I set my vconsole.conf file to be like this:

```
KEYMAP=slovene
FONT=Lat2-Terminus16
```

But when I try to type my Slovenian letters after reboot, instead of the letter **č** I get **A''** and I also get some wierd symbols for letters like **ž**, **đ**, **š** as well as capital versions of the same.

**Q1:** Why isn't my vconsole.conf applied?

**Q2:** Is it possible that letters just cant be rendered?

Comment: It does. I use boskop font and a customized keymap. probably those font/keymap file are incorrectly named

Comment: Does anyone here know what is the best setting if i want to use letters: đĐžŽšŠčČćĆ ? These are the only ones that i have problems with...

Comment: I have tried putting all arguments in double quotes and then rebuild with **mkinitcpio -p linux**, but nothing changed... Then i allso tried adding "radeon" under **MODULES** inside **/etc/mkinitcio.conf** but situation isn't resolved.

Comment: I found a solution! In my case a problem was because i didn't add **LANG=en_GB.UTF-8** in my **/etc/locale.conf**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to this question is now a bit different, because Arch Linux configuration has changed. For slovenian letters to work we now need to set file `/etc/vconsole.conf` to be:

```
KEYMAP=slovene
FONT=lat2a-16
```